# How to change JSESSIONID in Struts 2

Tags: java, authentication, session, struts2, httpsession

I should assign unique `JSESSIONID` after authentication. The `JSESSIONID` before authentication and after authentication should always be different.

So, how can I do this using Struts 2?

Comment: Don't use Struts 2.0, use Struts 2.3.16.3

Comment: okey..but can you please provide any login example

Comment: What's the point of doing this?

Comment: how to maintain session id throughout the application can you please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to following

http://nickcoblentz.blogspot.in/2008/09/jsessionid-regeneration-in-struts-2.html

Your class must implement SessionAware for this. There are 4 methods suggested for it .

One of them could be

```
((SessionMap)this.session).invalidate();
this.session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

Comment: how to maintain session id throughout the application can you please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Unique session id you can get if you get `HttpSession` object. In Struts2

```java
HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
System.out.println("Old session ID: "+session.getId());
//do authentication
session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(true);
System.out.println("New session ID: "+session.getId());
```